# Set-Content blanking files

Tags: powershell

I have the following script that is supposed to replace two keywords in a few SQL and batch scripts and then return them to the original:

```cs
# Modify TRIS 5 Scripts to account for database names used 
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "\tris5scripts\") -Rec

foreach ($file in $configFiles) {
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
        ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "TRISDemo4113", $databaseName } |
        Set-Content $file.PSPath
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "internal", $tris5Name } |
        Set-Content $file.PSPath
}

cmd.exe (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "\tris5scripts\execAll.cmd")
cmd.exe (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "\tris5scripts\Prepare Dashboard Statistics.cmd")

if ($databaseName -ne "TRISDemo4113" -or $tris5Name -ne "internal") {
    $configFiles = Get-ChildItem (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "tris5scripts") -Rec
    foreach ($file in $configFiles) {
        (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
            ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $databaseName, "TRISDemo4113" } |
            Set-Content $file.PSPath
        ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $tris5Name, "internal" } |
            Set-Content $file.PSPath
    }
}
```

What is happening though is that the script makes every file in this folder blank. I'm not sure how as I have used this exact code snippet in another script and it works fine. It seems to get to the two cmd.exe calls and does nothing because every file is blank now.

All I am trying to do is change those two values in the files:

1. "TRIS4133" → `$databaseName`
2. "internal" → `$tris5Name`

Comment: Your respective 2nd `Foreach-Object` calls receive no pipeline input and therefore output nothing, which makes `Set-Content $file.PSPath` write a 0-byte file.

Comment: I added a second Get-Content and also wrote $file.PSpath to console, it is changing the values in the file, however, it isn't running the two batch files. it just exits the script at that point. no error messages.

Comment: You need `/c` in order to have `cmd.exe` process commands, including executing batch files

Comment: You don't need `cmd.exe` in the first place. Just use the call operator (`&`). You may need double quotes around the path, though (`& "$(Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "\tris5scripts\execAll.cmd")"`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Good point about `&`, but you don't need double-quoting: PowerShell automatically double-quotes the results of expressions as needed.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, both your approaches worked, however, I ended up converting the batch files to a PowerShell loop to just call every SQL script in a folder. I also had to add [regex]::escape( to my replace. Again thanks for the help.